# Issues with wrapping Java program with Python's subprocess module

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a small java program that I can run from the command line using this syntax:

`java -jar EXEV.jar -s:myfile`

This java program print some data to the screen and I want redirect `stdout` into a file called `output.txt`.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def wrapper(*args):
    process = Popen(list(args), stdout=PIPE)
    process.communicate()[0]
    return process

x = wrapper('java', '-jar', 'EXEV.jar', '-s:myfile', '>', 'output.txt')
```

When I run the above, `output.txt` is never written to and Python does not throw any errors. Can anyone help me figure out the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to either use `stdout=output` where `output` is an open file for writing to 'output.txt' and remove the output redirection from the command, or leave the output redirection in the command and use `shell=True` with no `stdout` argument:

**Option 1:**

```
from subprocess import Popen

def wrapper(*args):
    output = open('output.txt', w)
    process = Popen(list(args), stdout=output)
    process.communicate()
    output.close()
    return process

x = wrapper('java', '-jar', 'EXEV.jar', '-s:myfile')
```

**Option 2:**

```
from subprocess import Popen

def wrapper(*args):
    process = Popen(' '.join(args), shell=True)
    process.communicate()
    return process

x = wrapper('java', '-jar', 'EXEV.jar', '-s:myfile', '>', 'output.txt')
```

Comment: And of these, the first is better: there's no reason to use the shell's redirection when Python provides the facilities already.